# File upload not working in Capacitor-converted Angular mobile app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, file-upload, capacitor

`I have developed an Angular web application and recently converted it into a mobile app using Capacitor. The application includes a feature to upload files, which works perfectly fine in the web version but encounters issues in the mobile app.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
onFileselected(event: Event) {
    this.inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (this.inputElement.files && this.inputElement.files.length > 0) {
      this.selectedFile = this.inputElement.files[0];
      if (!this.isValidFile(this.selectedFile)) {
        alert('Invalid file type. Please select a PDF, JPG or PNG file.');
        this.inputElement.value = ''; // Clear the file input
        this.selectedFile = null!;
      }
    }
  }

  uploadDocument() {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('document', this.selectedFile);
    if (this.selectedFile && this.isValidFile(this.selectedFile)) {
      if (!this.validateFileSize(this.selectedFile)) {
        alert("File size under 200KB");
        return;
      }
      if (this.document.documentId == undefined) {
        this.document.documentId = 0;
      }
      this.isDocUploaded = false;
      this.documentService.postDocument(this.userId, this.documentTypeId, this.document.documentId, formdata).subscribe((data) => {
        this.isDocUploaded = data as boolean;
        if (this.isDocUploaded == true) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            text: 'Updated Successfully',
            allowOutsideClick: false
          });
        } else {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            text: 'Something went wrong!',
            allowOutsideClick: false
          });
        }
        this.inputElement!.value = '';
        this.getDocumentForUpdate(this.documentTypeId);

      })
    } else {
      alert('Please select a valid PDF or JPG file.');
    }
  }
```

The issue I'm facing is that the file upload feature does not work as expected in the mobile app. The file selection event is triggered correctly, and the validation functions for file type and size work as expected. However, when the upload function is called, the file does not get uploaded.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

- Verified that necessary permissions (android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) are added in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
- Reviewed the file upload process and ensured that the correct API endpoint is being called.
- Checked the server-side code to confirm that it's correctly configured to receive and process file uploads.